# DataDog custom metrics not showing up graph using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datadog

We are trying to integrate DataDog with our Ruby On Rails app. Our ROR app will continuously add users, update users and delete users every second.

I have integrated Datadog to monitor the no. of users added, updated and deleted through the graph provided by Datadog.

I installed the datadog agent using the command for Ubuntu Aws instance.

I got a free trial for 14 days.

I followed this document for **dogstatd-ruby gem** : https://github.com/DataDog/dogstatsd-ruby

After that i wrote the code in my ruby project like below :

```
require 'statsd'

dogstatsd = Statsd.new('MY_API_KEY')

user_data = ExportUser.find_by_userID(user["userId"].to_s)

if user_data.nil?
   dogstatsd.increment('custom.users.added')  #increment dogstat if a user is added and below query is run

   #new record, go ahead with insertion
   user_new = ExportUser.new(user)
   @status = user_new.save

else
   dogstatsd.increment('custom.users.updated') #increment dogstat if a user is updated and below query is run

   #existing record, go ahead with updation
   @status = user_data.update_attributes(user)
end
```

Here i dont see "custom.users.updated" and "custom.users.added" graph in the metrics explorer.

I would really appreciate if any1 help me out to set the graph for these 2 metrics in Datadog account. please let me know if i missed anything here.

Answer (score 4):

Just a few items to note to get this working:

`dogstatsd = Statsd.new('MY_API_KEY')`

This line of code is trying to use your API key to establish a statsD connection, but this should actually be trying to establish the statsD connection via the statsD port currently configured on your Agent as seen here:

`Create a stats instance.
statsd = Statsd.new('localhost', 8125)`

> The easiest way to get your custom metrics into Datadog is to send them to DogStatsD, a metrics aggregation server bundled with the Datadog Agent (in versions 3.0 and above). DogStatsD implements the StatsD protocol, along with a few extensions for special Datadog features.

http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/dogstatsd/

If you would not like to deploy an Agent on the host running the RoR application, you can utilize DogAPI gem:

https://github.com/DataDog/dogapi-rb

Which has additional documentation to get this custom metrics submitted:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dogapi'

api_key = "abcdef123456"

dog = Dogapi::Client.new(api_key)

dog.emit_point('some.metric.name', 50.0, :host => "my_host", :device => "my_device")
```

If you have additional questions, please reach out to support@datadoghq.com

Comment: Thanks so much @Andrew. In that emit_point method, what is the value of "device"?

Comment: The value of `:device` in this case was an additional tag.  This allows them to break down the metric by host or device.  Hope this helps.  Sorry for the late response.

Here is a good link to get you started:

http://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204312749-Getting-started-with-tags